Assemble and send LLC protocol packet by powershell
need to send LLC discovery packet from powershell. Have zero experience in this, spend some time with searching examples. Finaly have this
# Ensure this script is run as Administrator for raw socket permissions
param (
    [string]$destMac = "01-19-a7-52-76-96"   # Destination MAC address
)

# Define LLC Frame Structure
$llcHeader = @(0xAA, 0xAA, 0x03)  # DSAP, SSAP, Control field

# Define Custom LLC Payload
$llcPayload = @( 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00
)

# Assemble the full LLC frame by appending the payload after the LLC header
$llcFrame = $llcHeader + $llcPayload

# Convert MAC address to byte array
function Convert-MacToBytes {
    param ([string]$mac)
    return $mac -split '-' | ForEach-Object { [Convert]::ToByte($_, 16) }
}

$destMacBytes = Convert-MacToBytes -mac $destMac

# Create raw socket and send the frame
$socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.Socket([System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork, [System.Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Raw, [System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::Raw)
$socket.SetSocketOption([System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel]::Socket, [System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName]::Broadcast, $true)

# Create byte array for the full Ethernet frame
$ethernetFrame = $destMacBytes + $llcFrame

# Send the packet
try {
    $socket.Send($ethernetFrame)
    Write-Output "LLC packet sent successfully."
} catch {
    Write-Output "Failed to send LLC packet: $_"
} finally {
    $socket.Close()
}   

but it print:

Failed to send LLC packet: Exception calling "Send" with "1"
argument(s): "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because
the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket
using a sendto call) no address was supplied"

what could be wrong here?

Does it make a difference with $socket.EnableBroadcast = $true?

thanks for hint, but same message

You're using Send which requires a connected socket. You probably want to be using SendTo.

Failed to send LLC packet: Cannot find an overload for "SendTo" and the argument count: "1".

@user2956477 You need to supply a destination when calling SendTo: $socket.SendTo($ethernetFrame, [System.Net.IPEndPoint]::new(0, 0))

Failed to send LLC packet: Exception calling "SendTo" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: buffer"

You still need to construct the payload/frame data you want to send

isn't it done here? $llcFrame = $llcHeader + $llcPayload
